# Getting TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, django-2.2

I have a model table by the name of Branches which is to be filed automatically from the CSV file hosted online. But, I keep getting the error

How I can resolve this?
Thanks

```
from django.db import models

class Branches(models.Model):

    ifsc       = models.CharField(max_length=1009)
    bank_id    = models.IntegerField()
    branch     = models.CharField(max_length=1009)
    address    = models.CharField(max_length=1500)
    city       = models.CharField(max_length=1999)
    district   = models.CharField(max_length=1999)
    state      = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    bank_name  = models.CharField(max_length=1000)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.branch

from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from io import StringIO
import csv

for row in urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/snarayanank2/indian_banks/dc7ac64137ecf24bfc564f3d6151331215cf4783/bank_branches.csv'):
    Branches.objects.create(ifsc=row['ifsc'], bank_id=row['bank_id'], branch=row['branch'], address=row['address'], city=row['city'], district=row['district'], state=row['state'], bank_name=row['bank_name'])
```

Comment: Notice than `row` is just a string encoded in bytes. You can't use it as dictionary.
I would `split()` the string and use indices to get the values I need:
```
for row in urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/snarayanank2/indian_banks/dc7ac64137ecf24bfc564f3d6151331215cf4783/bank_branches.csv'):
    Branches.objects.create(ifsc=row.split[0], ... , bank_name=row.split[7])
```

Comment: It's giving me this error now; TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Daniel Nudelmans comment, this is how you would use `split` with your current code:

```
for row in urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/snarayanank2/...'):
    row = row.split(",")
    # row is now a list containing all the values from the row
    Branches.objects.create(ifsc=row[0], bank_id=row[1], branch=row[2], address=row[3], city=row[4], district=row[5], state=row[6], bank_name=row[7])
```

Keep in mind if the CSV has headers (like "ifsc", "bank_id", etc. as the first row), in the first iteration of the for loop, `row` will be the names of the headers.